# How do you pass arguments to docker run entrypoint?

Tags: docker, command-line

```
>docker run --entrypoint "dotnet test" api-tests
```

This says it can't find the executable in the path variable.

```
>docker run --entrypoint "dotnet" api-tests
```

This works but doesn't do anything.

How do you pass multiple arguments?

e.g. `dotnet test UnitTests.csproj  --logger trx;LogFileName=/tests/test-results.trx`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whatever is after the image name replaces any defined CMD and is sent as parameter to the entrypoint.

So if you have an entrypoint defined, that you want to pass 'dotnet test' to, you'd do

```
docker run api-tests dotnet test
```

An example could be the alpine/curl image, that runs curl with the arguments you pass.

```
docker run --rm alpine/curl -s https://www.google.com/
```

will fetch the front page of Google. The parameters are just `-s https://www.google.com/`. The image has `curl` as the entrypoint, so you don't need to specify that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the `docker run --entrypoint` command, only the first shell word (the actual container-side binary to run) goes there.  The remaining arguments have to go after the image name, as the "command" arguments in the `docker run` command syntax.

```sh
docker run \
  --entrypoint dotnet \
  api-tests \
  test UnitTests.csproj --et=cetera
```

However, you can design your image to avoid needing this.  If the image uses `CMD` to declare its primary command and not `ENTRYPOINT`, then you can similarly provide the override command in the "command" part of the `docker run` command.

```sh
CMD ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"] # and not ENTRYPOINT
```

```sh
docker run --rm api-tests \
  dotnet test UnitTests.csproj --et=cetera
```

I tend to reserve `ENTRYPOINT` for a wrapper script that ends in `exec "$@"`, so it still runs the `CMD`, or for a `FROM scratch` image where it's literally impossible to run anything other than the single binary in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Just add them all the way in the end.
For `ENTRYPOINT` it adds to whatever was specified in the dockerfile.
In case `CMD` was used it will replace it.

so use :

```
docker run api-tests test
```

if you have `ENTRYPOINT dotnet` in your dockerfile.
or:

```
docker run api-tests dotnet test
```

if you have `CMD this-will-be-replaced` in your dockerfile